# /sys/ documentation?

Tags: linux, man

Are there any man pages on the `/sys/` directory and how devices are setup? I'm hoping that there may be something similar to `man proc`, but can't really find anything to push me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "how devices are set up"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How devices are "set up", in general, has nothing to do with `/sys`. Most likely you are looking for information about [`udev`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udev) or another hotplugging daemon.

You can find authoritative information about `/sys` (for which, the underlying filesystem is called `sysfs`) in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt).

Answer (score 3):

The `/sys` directory is called `sysfs`. You can find out about it:

- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)
- [official kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt)

Comment: Juts my 2 cents. The details are not sufficient. The man page for proc elaborates more than pointing to the procfs filesystem. The link https://askubuntu.com/questions/720471/whats-the-sys-directory-for has a better explanation.